How to create a new view in eclipse rcp based application
I have an eclipse rcp based application.
There are tabs like call hierarchy, search, problems etc same as there in eclipse.
Now I want to create a custom search tab , and want to name this tab as "Reference".
I want to show the search results in this new custom tab.
Is it possible to create a custom tab and show the search results over there.

Sure, and there is a lot of documentation and tutorials (like e.g. these tutorials) for this. There is also a template for this in the New Plug-in wizard: File > New > Other...: Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project, in the New Plug-in Project dialog hit twice Next, enable the Create a plug-in using a template checkbox and choose a View contribution template.

hi thanks for replying
i am still not able to find how can i create my own tab and show search results over there. as for search eclipse is using NewSearchUI which automatically opens the search results in search tab

Far too broad for Stack Overflow. Look at the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point.

but even if i'll create a new view, how will i show the search results in this custom view

Your custom view might provide a setInput(...) method for this. However, for a better user experience, your search results have to be displayed in the existing Search view.
